# Conditional Formatting - multiple conditions plus a wildcard text match

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

My custom conditional formatting formula is as follows:

Formula = `=AND($D2="TEST",$P2>=95,$P2<=199.99)`

However, I'm wanting to match **ANYTHING** in the D column that has "test" in it. For Example "Test 1", "Test King","Test" should all be matches.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH`.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TEST",$D2)),$P2>=95,$P2<=199.99)
```

Use `FIND` instead of `SEARCH` if you want this to be case-sensitive.